# AWS Redshift ERROR: numeric column type is not supported by CREATE MODEL as TARGET / RETURN

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following SQL Syntax in Redshift to create a linear regression model:

```
CREATE MODEL CostRegressionModel
FROM ( SELECT 
age,
sex,
bmi,
children,
smoker,
region,
charges as target_label
FROM
"dev"."public"."payout_training") 
TARGET target_label
FUNCTION CostRegression
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::070649885991:role/LabRole'
MODEL_TYPE LINEAR_LEARNER 
PROBLEM_TYPE REGRESSION
OBJECTIVE 'MSE'
SETTINGS(
    S3_BUCKET 'acmemlout',
    MAX_RUNTIME 15000
);
```

I have read through the documentation here and I cannot find anything that reflects this problem:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_MODEL.html

This is the SQL create statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.payout_training (
    id bigint ENCODE az64,
    age integer ENCODE az64,
    sex character varying(256) ENCODE lzo,
    bmi numeric(10, 2) ENCODE az64,
    children integer ENCODE az64,
    smoker character varying(256) ENCODE lzo,
    region
        character varying(256) ENCODE lzo,
        charges numeric(10, 2) ENCODE az64
) DISTSTYLE AUTO;
```

I'm not exactly sure the how, what or why in relation to this, but could really do with some assistance on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html

> select cast(pricepaid as integer) from sales where salesid=100;
>
> pricepaid
> ----------- 162 (1 row)

Alteration to script which so far appears to be working:

```
CREATE MODEL CostRegressionModel
FROM ( SELECT 
age,
sex,
bmi,
children,
smoker,
region,
CAST(charges as float) as target_label
FROM
"dev"."public"."payout_training") 
TARGET target_label
FUNCTION CostRegression
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::070649885991:role/LabRole'
MODEL_TYPE LINEAR_LEARNER 
PROBLEM_TYPE REGRESSION
OBJECTIVE 'MSE'
SETTINGS(
    S3_BUCKET 'acmemlout',
    MAX_RUNTIME 15000
);
```

I had tried to do an ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN TYPE but Redshift did not allow it.

But the above alteration, casting the type within the query has put the model into training mode.

Just in case anyone every comes across the same issue again.